# [Android][Google Maps]: Get the Address of location on touch

Tags: android, google-maps, geocoding, google-geocoder

I have been googling this for hours but no luck so far.

I want to get the address of the location where the map is touched / tapped.

I understand that in order to get the address i need to reverse geocode the coordinates. But how do i get the coordinates from the map in the first place?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

All you need to do is set up a [OnMapClickListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener), and then the `onMapClick()` override will give you a `LatLng` object.  Then, use a [Geocoder](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Geocoder.html) object to get the address of the point that was just clicked on.

In this simple example, I've also added a Marker every time the user clicks a new point on the map.

Here is the main piece of functionality that you need:

```
mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
            //save current location
            latLng = point;

            List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
            try {
                addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude,1);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            android.location.Address address = addresses.get(0);

            if (address != null) {
                StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                    sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i) + "\n");
                }
                Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            //remove previously placed Marker
            if (marker != null) {
                marker.remove();
            }

            //place marker where user just clicked
            marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                    .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

        }
    });
```

Here is the full class that I used to test this:

```
public class MapsActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private LatLng latLng;
    private Marker marker;
    Geocoder geocoder;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        geocoder = new Geocoder(this, Locale.getDefault());

        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        setUpMapIfNeeded();
    }

    private void setUpMapIfNeeded() {
        // Do a null check to confirm that we have not already instantiated the map.
        if (mMap == null) {
            // Try to obtain the map from the SupportMapFragment.
            mMap = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map))
                    .getMap();
            // Check if we were successful in obtaining the map.
            if (mMap != null) {
                setUpMap();
            }
        }
    }

    private void setUpMap() {

        mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        mMap.getUiSettings().setMapToolbarEnabled(false);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {
                //save current location
                latLng = point;

                List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();
                try {
                    addresses = geocoder.getFromLocation(point.latitude, point.longitude,1);
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

                android.location.Address address = addresses.get(0);

                if (address != null) {
                    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
                    for (int i = 0; i < address.getMaxAddressLineIndex(); i++){
                        sb.append(address.getAddressLine(i) + "\n");
                    }
                    Toast.makeText(MapsActivity.this, sb.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }

                //remove previously placed Marker
                if (marker != null) {
                    marker.remove();
                }

                //place marker where user just clicked
                marker = mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(point).title("Marker")
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.defaultMarker(BitmapDescriptorFactory.HUE_MAGENTA)));

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Result of tapping the map in two different points:

[image]

[image]

Comment: As an android newb I really appreciate the elaborate answer

Comment: @potato300: you're right, the answer is the same but I can get that it's easier to understand, I was in the subway, got no IDE at disposal ;)

Comment: @DanielNugent I have tried the Geocoder to get the address from the latitude and longitude, but it doesn't provides me with the exact address of my current location, it gives the address of a nearby street or place.

Answer (score 1):

Google Map has callbacks to do that [like this one](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener) or [this one](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener).

Just implement them in your code and as soon as they're fired, just make a reverse geocode the coordinates. You actually found the most complicated part (you understood that you need to reverse geocode).