# Load map with drop pins in the alertdialog to the main xml layout in android development

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I have an xml layout with a button and if I click on it an alertdialog will pop up with a working map on it, what i want is to get the map with drop pin in the alertdialog and put it on the main xml layout, this is for android development.

Comment: Please show us what you have tried

Comment: map on the alertdialog works fine now, but putting it on the main layout is still in progress Sir....

Comment: This question is a bit too broad currently.  As for your dialog, you could capture map click events and place a Marker (Pin) where the user clicks, and save the point, take a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248257/androidgoogle-maps-get-the-location-on-touch

Comment: sorry but i am new here in stack overflow, how can i post here pictures and source codes  so that i can show you what i've done.

Comment: There's an edit link on the lower left of your question, you can edit it to add your code, use the `{}` button to format your code.

Comment: problem solved, thanks by the way to all of you. :)