# Android App using Google Maps with marker on touch and search via address

Tags: android, google-maps, android-studio, google-maps-markers, google-maps-api-2

I've got a question to you guys - I want to get something like this:

- `Fragment` in an `Activity` which show a map with `marker` placed on my `LatLng` position on start.
- There will be an `EditText` when I can type address which should be found - Let's say I would like to search it after I click a button (cause it is easier to implement than `AutoCompleteTextView` or something like that) and create a `marker` on that place what was found.
- But whenever I touch or tap on this map I would like to create new `marker` (and delete the old one, there should be only one marker at a time).

Please help me with steps which should be done by me.

Comment: For the marker-on-tap part, have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31248257/androidgoogle-maps-get-the-location-on-touch

Comment: For the EditText/Address part of your question, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574644/how-can-i-find-the-latitude-and-longitude-from-address

Comment: For the first point, showing the current location on launch, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34582370/how-can-i-show-current-location-on-a-google-map-on-android-marshmallow