# How to get latitude and longitude of select location on google map in android studio

Tags: java, android, google-maps

I am opening map using intent in android studio I select location on google map I want to get details about that location

Comment: Have you tried calling the Places API with that latitude and longitude?

Comment: Please add some code to better understand what you're trying to achieve and to make your question more easier to answer.

Comment: I have no code I am doing this first time like Uri gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("geo:0,0?q="+Uri.encode("Islamabad Capital Territory"));
                Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
                mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
                startActivity(mapIntent) I am opening map like this now I select locaiton on google map so I need details of that location

Comment: I think you are looking for https://stackoverflow.com/a/31249720/1318946

Answer (score 1):

you don't have any access to get latitude and longitude from google map application.
you should open the google map in a fragment like this:

in layout:

```
            <fragment
                android:id="@+id/shop_fragment"
                android:name="com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="250dp" />
```

in Java:

```
 public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {

    mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);

        }
    });
```

you must implement your activity to generate onMapClick.
then

```
@Override
public void onMapClick(LatLng point) {

   double shopLt = point.latitude;
   double shopLn = point.longitude;

}
```